# Need help xml CDATA in flash as2

Tags: xml, flash, cdata

i need help with CDATA when i use it it show in browser window and all attributes that inside CDATA

For example my xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

    <project>
        <projecttext>
<contenttext><![CDATA[<h1>text</h1>]]></contenttext>
        </projecttext>
   </project>
```

and i get in browser window this

```
<h1>text</h1>
```

my flash script is

```
//
//IMPORTS AND STAGE INIT
//
stop();
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.filters.*;
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
import caurina.transitions.properties.ColorShortcuts;
ColorShortcuts.init();
//
Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
Stage.align = "TL";
//
//XML DOCUMENT INIT
//
var XMLdaten = new XML();
XMLdaten.ignoreWhite = true;
XMLdaten.load(_global.modulexml);
//XMLdaten.load("xml/contentpage.xml");
//
//MEDIA LOADER
//
mediaLoader = function (item, link, mcap) {
    var my_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    var mclListener:Object = new Object();
    my_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
    //this happens when loading is completed
    mclListener.onLoadComplete = function(mc:MovieClip):Void  {
        Tweener.removeTweens(item);
        Tweener.removeTweens(mcap);
        Tweener.addTween(item,{_x:0, time:1, transition:"easeOutExpo"});
        Tweener.addTween(mcap,{_x:0, time:1, transition:"easeOutExpo", delay:0.1});
        mc_project.scrollpane.container.smask._height = mc_project.scrollpane.container._height;
    };
    my_mcl.loadClip(link,item);
};
//
//ADD PROJECT DETAIL MODE
//
addDetail = function () {
    //
    attachMovie("mc_project","mc_project",getNextHighestDepth(),{_x:Math.floor(Stage.width/2)-470, _y:Stage.height, _alpha:100});
    scbgr = new flash.geom.Rectangle();
    scbgr.left = 5;
    scbgr.right = 10;
    scbgr.top = 5;
    scbgr.bottom = 70;
    pheight = Math.floor(Stage.height-_root.XMLoptions_headerheight-_root.XMLoptions_footerheight);
    mc_project.scrollpane.scbg.scale9Grid = scbgr;
    mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height = pheight-95-Math.floor(slideshowheight);
    mc_project.scrollpane.smask._height = pheight-95-Math.floor(slideshowheight);
    //
    //ASSIGNING TEXT
    //
    //MOVING TEXT IF CONTENT EMPTY
    //
    mc_project.scrollpane.container.content_txt.autoSize = "left";
    mc_project.scrollpane.container.content_txt.styleSheet = cssfile;
    mc_project.scrollpane.container.content_txt.htmlText = XMLdaten_projecttext;
    //
    //ASSIGNING MEDIA
    //
    myoffset = 0;
    mc_project.scrollpane.container.content_txt._width = 890;
    mc_project.scrollpane.container.smask._height = pheight-95;
    //
    //MAKE PROJECT DETAIL VISIBLE
    //
    mc_project.scrollpane.container.setMask(mc_project.scrollpane.smask);
    Tweener.removeTweens(mc_project);
    lockText = function () {
        mc_project.scrollpane.container.content_txt.autoSize = "none";
    };
    if (ss_activated) {
        Tweener.addTween(mc_project,{_y:slideshowheight+5, time:0.5, transition:"easeOutExpo"});
    } else {
        Tweener.addTween(mc_project,{_y:5, time:0.5, transition:"easeOutExpo"});
    }
    setTimeout(lockText,100);
    //
    //PROJECT TEXT SCROLLING
    //
    sa = 30;
    //
    if (mc_project.scrollpane.container._height<=mc_project.scrollpane.smask._height) {
        mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._visible = false;
        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._visible = false;
    } else {
        mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._visible = true;
        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._visible = true;
    }
    //        
    mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar.onRollOver = function() {
        this.useHandCursor = true;
        Tweener.addTween(this.hover,{_alpha:100, time:0.5, transition:"easeOutSine"});
    };
    mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar.onRollOut = function() {
        Tweener.addTween(this.hover,{_alpha:0, time:0.5, transition:"easeInSine"});
    };
    mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar.onReleaseOutside = function() {
        Tweener.addTween(this.hover,{_alpha:0, time:0.5, transition:"easeInSine"});
    };
    //on scrollbar press            
    mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar.onMouseDown = function() {
        if (this.hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse) && mc_project.scrollpane.container._height>mc_project.scrollpane.smask._height) {
            this.startDrag(false,mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._x,mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._y,mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._x,mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height-this._height);
            mc_project.scrollpane.container.onEnterFrame = scrollThumbs;
            dragging = true;
        }
    };
    //on scrollbar release
    mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar.onMouseUp = function() {
        stopDrag();
        dragging = false;
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    };
    //scrolling functionality
    scrollThumbs = function () {
        var positionvar = -this._parent.scrollbar._y*(((this._height-this._parent.scrollbar._height+5)/(this._parent.scbg._height-this._parent.scrollbar._height))-1);
        this.Y = (positionvar-this._y)*.2;
        this._y += this.Y;
        this._y = parseInt(this._y);
        if (Math.abs(positionvar-this._y)<1 && !dragging) {
            delete this.onEnterFrame;
        }
    };
    //    
    //MOUSE SCROLL FUNCTION
    //
    function mousescrolling() {
        mouseListener = new Object();
        //
        mouseListener.onMouseWheel = function(delta) {
            if (mc_project.scrollpane.container._height>mc_project.scrollpane.smask._height) {
                if (delta>0) {
                    stopDrag();
                    mc_project.scrollpane.container.onEnterFrame = scrollThumbs;
                    if (mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y>mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._y && (mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y-mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._y)<sa) {
                        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y -= Math.floor(mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y-mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._y);
                    } else if (mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y>mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._y && (mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y-mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._y)>=sa) {
                        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y -= sa;
                    }
                } else {
                    stopDrag();
                    mc_project.scrollpane.container.onEnterFrame = scrollThumbs;
                    if (mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y<(mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._height) && (mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._height)<sa) {
                        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y += Math.floor(mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._height);
                    } else if (mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y<(mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._height) && (mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y-mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._height)>=sa) {
                        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y += sa;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);
        return mouseListener;
    }
    mouseListener = mousescrolling();
};
//
//RESIZE POSITIONING
//
position = function () {
    pheight = Math.floor(Stage.height-_root.XMLoptions_headerheight-_root.XMLoptions_footerheight);
    //
    mc_project._x = Math.floor(Stage.width/2)-470;
    if (ss_activated) {
        slideshow._x = Math.floor(Stage.width/2)-460;
    }
    mc_project._alpha = 100;
    mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._height = pheight-90-Math.floor(slideshowheight);
    mc_project.scrollpane.smask._height = pheight-90-Math.floor(slideshowheight);
    mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._y = 0;
    //
    if (mc_project.scrollpane.container._height<=mc_project.scrollpane.smask._height) {
        mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._visible = false;
        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._visible = false;
    } else {
        mc_project.scrollpane.scbg._visible = true;
        mc_project.scrollpane.scrollbar._visible = true;
    }
};
//
resizeListener = new Object();
resizeListener.onResize = function() {
    position();
};
Stage.addListener(resizeListener);
//
//XML DOCUMENT LOAD & DATA ASSIGN
//
XMLdaten.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {
        //
        XMLdaten_medialink = [];
        XMLdaten_mediaheight = [];
        XMLdaten_mediacaption = [];
        //
        maxv = _root.maxv;
        if (maxv != undefined) {
            pheight = Stage.height-maxv;
        } else {
            pheight = Stage.height;
        }
        regularImageLoad = function (link, item) {
            my_mcl = new MovieClipLoader();
            mclListener = new Object();
            my_mcl.loadClip(link,item);
        };
        //
        XMLdaten_projecttext = XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[0];
        if (XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[1].attributes["height"] != undefined && XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[1].attributes["height"] != "") {
            ss_activated = true;
            slideshowtype = XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[1].attributes["slideshowtype"];
            slideshowheight = parseInt(XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[1].attributes["height"]);
            _global.slideshowxml = XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[1].attributes["slideshowxml"];
            createEmptyMovieClip("slideshow",getNextHighestDepth(),{_x:0, _y:0});
            slideshow._x = Math.floor(Stage.width/2)-460;
            slideshow._y = 3;
            regularImageLoad(slideshowtype,slideshow);
        }else{
            slideshowheight = 0;
        }
        //         
        //Load Stylesheet
        cssfile = new TextField.StyleSheet();
        cssfile.load("xml/styles.css");
        cssfile.onLoad = function(success) {
            if (success) {
                cssloaded = true;
                if(XMLdaten_projecttext!=""){
                    addDetail();
                }
            } else {
                cssloaded = false;
            }
        };
        //
        xmlloaded = true;
    } else {
        xmlloaded = false;
    }
};
```

i use xml business portfolio template

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [blog post](http://hailinhe1986-163-com.javaeye.com/blog/507791) on the same topic.

Apparently, one of two things is happening:

1. You are in fact not accessing CDATA correctly (This is what heartcode is referring to):

   > Now, the way that you should be
   >   accessing CDATA in Flash is perhaps a
   >   little different to what you’d expect.
   >   CDATA should have no effect on how you
   >   access your XML – it’s a parsing
   >   instruction, right?.  Well Flash
   >   treats it as part of the XML
   >   structure, so if you want to access
   >   the data inside the CDATA element, you
   >   have to treat the CDATA as a node in
   >   itself.  Its actually quite easy
   >   though.  Instead of accessing the
   >   contents of CDATA with
   >   childNode.nodeValue or childNodes, you
   >   should be using
   >   childNode.firstChild.nodeValue.

   In your case, it should be XMLdaten.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue, as childNodes[0] yields the same node as firstChild.
2. The Flash player isn't parsing the CDATA correctly

   > If you run a few traces on HTML
   >   formatting that you try to send via
   >   CDATA, you’ll notice that all of the <
   >   and > characters are transformed into
   >   their encoded versions, < and >.
   >   This poses a minor problem because if
   >   you just try to whack HTML from your
   >   XML into a dynamic textbox, the
   >   formatting won’t work properly and
   >   you’ll get the characters < and >
   >   appearing, along with the HTML
   >   formatting commands – because the <
   >   and > characters are encoded.

   Unless in your text you have any < or > characters you need displayed as such, you could run `XMLdaten_projecttext = XMLdaten_projecttext.split(’&lt;’).join(’<’).split(’&gt;’).join(’>’)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
XMLdaten_projecttext = XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Good luck, Rob

Comment: thank you only now all content disappeared and only show "null"

Comment: All right, then try this: XMLdaten_projecttext = XMLdaten.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;